# How to install minikube cluster without default images?

Tags: configuration, minikube

After the creation of minikube in my local machine. I see that the images created by default are the following.

[image]

I went trough the documentation and saw that we can provide some configuration that we can use in conjunction with this images. But I don't think I am using so many of this images.
May be for internal purposes some of this images are needed, but what if I don't want to have the dashboard for example?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#configuring-kubernetes

How can I start a minikube cluster without those images that are not required?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images for `addonManager, storageProvisioner, dashboardFrontend and dashboardMetrics`
come from [[minikube github repo]](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/19c8ddee9fa6d57dd1699dbb22de78d70bc2eab3/pkg/minikube/bootstrapper/images/images.go#L113) and are being added to a list of images to be pulled in [this line](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/19c8ddee9fa6d57dd1699dbb22de78d70bc2eab3/pkg/minikube/bootstrapper/images/kubeadm.go#L33).

As you can see there is no flag to disable pulling these images at minikube startup.

They are called `auxilary` images as they are "images that are helpful for running minikube" - according to comments in code.

So the only way to exclude those additional images from minikube startup is to remove those lines and compile modified code.